# Can I Control My Android Game with Arduino Gamepad

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, hc-05, android

I have a project that I need to make a game(guitar hero like rhythm game) on unity for android and develop a custom controller for it that works on mobile game. I decide to use Arduino and hc05 module for communication via bluetooth. But every tutorial that I watched on internet that phone used as a controller, I want to make it reverse. I want to use Arduino as a gamepad on Adnroid. Is that possible?

Comment: Not with a HC-05, unless you want to write your game to use serial communication specifically (i.e., be 100% custom with the control interface). HC-05 cannot be a game controller. Only serial.

Comment: Majenko is right, though there are other bluetooth boards, that support the HID protocol. You could search or them. Or you need to implement serial communication into your game for it working with the HC-05

Comment: So ESP32 can be a solution?